# Как провалиться в карточку товара ? Парсинг Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, web-scraping

Есть кусок HTML кода:

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 c compare-del-parent">
<div class="view-elem-colorbox-img">
        <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="relative">
    <a class="big-img uniqid-1001 cboxElement" href="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/b/220368.jpg" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368">
      <img src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/i/220368.jpg" data-src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/i/220368.jpg" class="lazyload img-thumbnail-lazyload-171" alt="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" style="display: inline-block;">
    </a>
              <div class="addimg">
      <div class="div-colorbox">
                                    <a class="nu big-img uniqid-1001 cboxElement uniqid-1002" href="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pb/220368.jpg" data-href="#" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368">
          <img src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pi/220368.jpg" data-src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pi/220368.jpg" class="lazyload img-thumbnail-lazyload-38" alt="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" style="display: inline-block;">
          </a>
                                                  <a class="nu big-img uniqid-1001 cboxElement uniqid-1002" href="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pb/220368-2.jpg" data-href="#" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368">
          <img src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pi/220368-2.jpg" data-src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pi/220368-2.jpg" class="lazyload img-thumbnail-lazyload-38" alt="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" style="display: inline-block;">
          </a>
                                                  <a class="nu big-img uniqid-1001 cboxElement uniqid-1002" href="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pb/220368-3.jpg" data-href="#" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368">
          <img src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pi/220368-3.jpg" data-src="https://img.oboi.ua/img/c/bn/cubiq/pi/220368-3.jpg" class="lazyload img-thumbnail-lazyload-38" alt="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" title="Обои BN Cubiq 220368" style="display: inline-block;">
          </a>
                                                                                      
                  </div>
      </div>
          </div>
      </div>
<div class="clear-10"></div>
<div class="mh60">
  <h2 class="subtitle c"><a class="u" href="/wallpaper-brands/bn/cubiq/220368/">Обои BN Cubiq 220368</a></h2>
</div>
    <span class="order-table-cost">958.32<br><span class="f12 pl4">грн/рулон</span><br><span class="f12 pl4">0,53 x 10,05</span></span>     <div class="w120px mv8 center-block">
        <div class="form-order input-group">
  <input class="form-control input-md order-query" size="5" value="" type="text" data-code="bn-cubiq-220368" data-cost="">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-md order-query-change" type="button" title="Добавить в корзину">Купить</button>
                      </span>
</div>
  </div>
<div class="pl0 pr0 mv8 center-block">
  
  На складе <b>25</b> (рулон)
      <div class="alert alert-danger mh20 p2 m0">
  <i class="icon-li icon-truck"></i>
                                      Отправим завтра
                                        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Это карточка товара в блоке товаров. Нужно провалиться внутрь карты, чтоб парсить все нужные х-ки товара. Как это сделать на Python ? Интересует сам механизм, чтоб применять в коде. Прикрепляю 2 скрина, чтоб было понятнее о чем вопрос
[image: Изображение, отвечающее коду]

[image: Внутри карточки, сюда надо попадать и парсить]

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно сделать отдельный запрос(перед этим спарсив ссылку на объявляение)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('a', class_='u').get('href')
response = requests.get(link)
```

и уже response распарсить